# How to inflate FABRevealMenu?

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, android-inflate

How can I inflate FABRevealMenu? ([the project's wiki page is here](https://github.com/HarinTrivedi/FABRevealMenu-master/wiki#how-to-use))

Since I'm newbie, I can't understand what layout to inflate which is mentioned in these rows:

> You can inflate custom view by two ways
>
> - app:menuCustomView="@layoutRes" // you can get custom view object by calling  getCustomView() on fabRevealMenu instance
> - setCustomView(View)

At the moment, I can't see any FABRevealMenu in my app and didn't get any error.

I added this to app_bar_main.xml:

```
<com.hlab.fabrevealmenu.view.FABRevealMenu
    android:id="@+id/fabMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:animateItems="true"
    app:menuBackgroundColor="@color/blue_semi_transparent"
    app:menuDirection="left"
    app:menuRes="@menu/main"
    app:menuSize="normal"
    app:menuTitleDisabledTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menuTitleFontFamily="@font/italiana"
    app:menuTitleTextColor="@color/white"
    app:overlayBackground="@color/colorBlack"
    app:showOverlay="true"
    app:showTitle="true" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to create a fab button first and then assign this feb menu on this button

```
final FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
final FABRevealMenu fabMenu = view.findViewById(R.id.fabMenu);

 //attach menu to fab
 fabMenu.bindAnchorView(fab);
 //set menu selection listener
 fabMenu.setOnFABMenuSelectedListener(this);
```

Dont forget to implement OnFABMenuSelectedListener in your activity/fragment

if you have any problem ask freely!!